# Is it possible to make the classpath the @rpath in a JNI library?

Tags: java, c++, macos, java-native-interface, rpath

I have a library that my JNI depends on, I would like it to be loaded relative to the classpath, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative to the `classpath`, no, it's not possible - libraries, including `.jnilib` follow the OS search path defined based on what the JRE assigns, then what the libraries themselves mention.

When you make the `.jnilib`, you can to add a linker flag to specify the rpath relative to the 'loader' path for the library, which will allow you to place dependent libraries in a location adjacent to the `.jnilib` itself, which can accomplish a similar behaviour:

```
libjni.jnilib: libjni.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $< -Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/../lib
```

The important item is the adding of `-Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/../lib` - which says tell the linker to add `@loader_path/../lib` to the `rpath` of the `.jnilib`.

The value `@loader_path` resolves to the location of the `.jnilib` file at run-time.

If you want to load dependencies based on the classpath, you'll actually have to find the libraries based on the classpath yourself and explicitly load them into the jre using `System.load()`, and then they should be pre-resolved by dyld when you load the library that the module depends on.

Comment: So you're saying that @loader_path is relative to where I'm loading my `jnilib` is? I have tried that assumption and it didn't work for me, but I'll try again since you mentioned it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, @loader_path is relative to the location of the jnilib on the file system, it acts in the same manner as the $ORIGIN variable for rpath under Linux

Comment: My library compile looks like this: `g++ -dynamiclib -rpath @loader_path -F /Users/nstuart/Downloads/myo-sdk -framework myo -framework JavaVM -o libmyo.jnilib *.o` and when I make my dependent library in the same directory, I still get `Library not loaded: @rpath/myo.framework/Versions/A/myo`

Comment: and if you copy `myo.framework` into the directory that `libmyo.jnilib` is loaded from then it will work, The -F option should be seen as the equivalent of the `-L` option for finding the framework file, unless you also add the same path to the rpath, it will not be able to find the library

Comment: I have copied the `myo.framework` directory to where I set the `@rpath`, but I still get that error. Are you aware of any JVM arguments I might be able to add for more information on the failure?

Comment: In that case you have `libmyo.jnilib` and `myo.framework` in the same directory? When I do that and compile and run a test project it works. The test project simply loads the `.jnilib` using System.loadLibrary("myo"); making sure that `java.library.path` is set to the directory containing `libmyo.jnilib` - sample code at https://github.com/petesh/jniwithrpath/tree/master

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63443/discussion-between-petesh-and-nicholas).